# Azure Active Directory B2C Hidden costs

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-front-door, azure-cost-calculation

We have been working with AAD B2C for a couple of months now and we realised that there is a decent amount of hidden costs. The [official billing model documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/billing) only shows the costs for the monthly authenticated users. In a lot of cases, Azure front door will have to be used. No company wants to use the default b2c domain as their new sign-in page for their clients.

Looking at the subscription cost, we have no idea which some of these services are linked to. There are multiple storage, bandwidth, and Azure Front Door services. [The pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/calculator/?service=active-directory) also does not include a warning about the hidden costs.

In a production environment, using Azure front door and with over 10k MAU. What else are we paying for?

Are we also paying for storing the user data? Are we paying extra because we have extension attributes set on our users? What about the costs for the Log Analytics, are those from the Custom Policy logging?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't pay to store the data or pay for extension attributes.

If you have log analytics set up for debugging, then yes.

The storage may be for the blob storage you use for the HTML and CSS files for branding?